# Unable to replace \xe2\x80\xa6\n in a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
data = "pizza won't divorce you pizza won't betray you pizza won't cheat on you pizza won't fight with you  why don't people just \xe2\x80\xa6\n"
```

and i want to find all `\[a-z][a-z][0-9]\` (\xe2\x80\xa6\ given at the end of `data` string) expressions from it, so that i can replace them. I tried the following codes:

`re.findall(r"\\[a-z][a-z][0-9]\\+", data)`

but it yields an empty list. Kindly help.

Comment: can you add what is your objective? what you want exactly..

Comment: I am guessing that `"\xe2\x80\xa6"` in your string is the unicode - [`"\u2026"`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) - `…` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define your string as `raw string` if you want that as python will try to convert the `unicode`.

```
data = r"pizza won't divorce you pizza won't betray you pizza won't cheat on you pizza won't fight with you  why don't people just \xe2\x80\xa6\n"

print re.findall(r"\\[a-z][a-z]?[0-9]+", data)
```

Output:`['\\xe2', '\\x80', '\\xa6']`

Comment: if data accidently has the character escapes that are used in Python bytestring literals then the data should be fixed upstream and converted to Unicode text first: `r"\xe2\x80\xa6".decode('string-escape').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian guess OP just wanted to get a list `\x` unicodes...he didnt want to convert it or something

Comment: OP may not understand the difference between bytes, Unicode strings and their text representations in Python source code but the answer should at least acknowledge that saner methods to work with text exist in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
print re.findall(r"\\[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,2}", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with text, you should use Unicode strings: `b"\xe2\x80\xa6"` bytestring is utf-8 encoded [**`u'…'`** (U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS)](https://codepoints.net/U+2026):

```
text = u"pizza won't divorce\u2026"
```

To replace it:

```
no_ellipsis = text.replace(u"\u2026", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that can help with Unicode issues called **ftfy**. Has saved me time and worth giving a go.

> https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
pip install ftfy
```

> https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/

**your example**

```
data = "pizza won't divorce you pizza won't betray you pizza won't cheat on you pizza won't fight with you  why don't people just \xe2\x80\xa6\n"

import ftfy
print(ftfy.fix_text(data))

output -->
"pizza won't divorce you pizza won't betray you pizza won't cheat on you pizza won't fight with you  why don't people just …"
```

note `\xe2\x80\xa6\n` has been replaced with `...`

**--Other examples--**

**Example 1**

```
import ftfy
print(ftfy.fix_text('uÌˆnicode'))

output -->
ünicode
```

**Example 2**

```
import ftfy
print(ftfy.fix_text('\xe2\x80\xa2'))

output -->
•
```

**Example 3**

```
import ftfy
print(ftfy.fix_text(u'\u2026'))

output -->
…
```